# Kali Linux Purple: Unable to install 'libgconf-2-4' package

Tags: apt, kali-linux, discord

I am attempting to install Spotify and Discord on my Kali Linux (Purple Edition) using `apt install <package name/deb file>`.

However i ran into dependency issues. Typically, Kali would install these dependencies automatically but it appears that it was impossible to install this dependency:

`libgconf-2-4`

To provide more information here are some additional information:

```
└─$ sudo apt install ./discord-0.0.29.deb                                                       
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'discord' instead of './discord-0.0.29.deb'
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 discord : Depends: libgconf-2-4 but it is not installable
           Recommends: libappindicator1 but it is not installable or
                       libayatana-appindicator1 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

```
└─$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Kali
Description:    Kali GNU/Linux Rolling
Release:        2023.3
Codename:       kali-rolling
```

```
└─$ sudo cat /etc/apt/sources.list                                                                                                           
# See https://www.kali.org/docs/general-use/kali-linux-sources-list-repositories/
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free non-free-firmware

# Additional line for source packages
# deb-src http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main contrib non-free non-free-firmware
```

I tried to install it manually by `sudo apt install libgconf-2-4` as many instructions online told to do so but it results in the package not being found:

`E: Unable to locate package libgconf-2-4`

I have tried to update the package list as well as fully update the entire system with success:

```
└─$ sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade -Vy && sudo apt autoremove -y && sudo apt autoclean
Hit:1 http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease                                                                                                                                  
Hit:2 http://mirror.aktkn.sg/kali kali-rolling InRelease                                                                                                                              
Hit:3 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease                                                                    
Ign:4 https://repo.hotspotshield.com/deb/rel/all release InRelease                                                                 
Hit:5 https://repo.hotspotshield.com/deb/rel/all release Release              
Ign:6 https://repo.hotspotshield.com/deb/rel/all release Release.gpg
Hit:7 https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/8.x/apt stable InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
```

And finally, I tried to fix broken installs by using:

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install
```

All these attempts did not progress the situation. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Hey, Kali Linux is definitely not the right platform to install discord on. That is said, right there, in Kali's official documentation under "should I use Kali Linux?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`libgconf-2-4` was [removed from Kali](https://pkg.kali.org/news/547356/gconf-326-8-removed-from-kali-rolling/) on August 7, following [its removal from Debian](https://bugs.debian.org/1043068). Since Kali is a rolling distribution, there’s no reliable way of installing the package — technically you could try to install an older copy of the package, but you would then have to deal with any problems that might cause in the future.

You’ll have to wait for an updated Discord package (or ask for one). Given that the library will not be available in Ubuntu 23.10, due for release next month, you shouldn’t have to wait too long.

(In any case, Kali isn’t a general-purpose distribution, so you shouldn’t rely on being able to install third-party packages there.)

Answer (score -1):

Me paso lo mismo intentando instalar Spotify.
Mi solución fue instalar el gestor de software "snap"

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install snapd

sudo snap install spotify
```

O en tu caso:

```
sudo snap install discord
```

Comment: esa es una solución temporal, por cierto.